# when are ethereum fees the lowest? Do they ever drop at a high rate?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, gas, cryptoeconomics

"Can  the prcies ever really drop ?Not a dollar but actually in terma of more then just a dollar or two ? a noticable rate? I know the less traffic the less gas but isthere any other ways to wrok-aound this ? maybe supply my own rates? i just think that the gas fees are quite crazy relative to other exchanges and currencies , why is that"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly save yourself on fees when you edit your gas with the help of Eth Gas Station. When you’re sending transactions from the likes of Metamask, the gas fee will automatically be prefilled for you